# (JAVA) array into multi-line string

Tags: java, arrays, tostring

Having quite a lot of trouble with returning an array as a multi line string.
let's say we have this:

```
Town arrayTown[] = new Town[Constants.MAX_TOWNS];

assume we add values to arrayTown.

public String toString(){
```

how do you go about returning every object in the array as a string, skipping a line between every object?

Comment: skipping a line..? not sure what you mean by that... add a new line after each string?

Comment: Do you know how to loop over the items in an array? Do you know how to generate a string one bit at a time, using StringBuilder? If you do, then you should be able to piece this together if you think on it for a bit. If you don't, you should definitely look into those -- they are fundamental Java skills. (There are other ways to accomplish this than iteration and StringBuilder, but that's an important one to know if you've just started learning Java.)

Comment: @Raz_Muh_Taz what I mean is showing a single value of the array per line once converted to a string.

Comment: @yshavit My teacher hasn't mentionned anything about stringbuilder. I'm indeed new to Java, and only have acquired the basics. Currently learning and have just started object-oriented programming java.

Comment: How about String concatenation? If that doesn't ring a bell either, then you should read this [open letter to students with homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems). The tldr (but really, you should read it) is that the more specific you make your question, the better it'll be received, and also the better chance you'll have of getting a good answer.

Comment: Take a look at `StringJoiner`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no Code is shown to reproduce a problem. What is a Town? How is it implemented? What is the context?

Answer (score 1):

```
Town arrayTown[] = new Town[Constants.MAX_TOWNS];

public String toString(){
String res = "";
for(Town i : arrayTown) {
    res+= i + "\n\n";
}
return res;
}
```

Should work. If you have any questions let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can try \r\n to append at the end of each string ,because The linefeed character \n is not the line separator in certain operating systems(like windows).
below is the sample code.

```
String[] arr;
        arr = new String[5];
        arr[0] = "Hai";
        arr[1] = "how are you";
        arr[2] = "I am Fine";
        arr[3] = "What about you";
        arr[4] = "ok,bye";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            sb.append(arr[i]+"\r\n ");
        }

        System.out.println("String is:"+sb.toString());
```